# With POSIX sockets API, when does actual packet buffering starts in socket?

Tags: networking, sockets

With POSIX socket API, the calls to read / write sockets generally follow: `socket()`, then `setsockopt()`, then `bind()`, then `listen() / accept() / connect()` for TCP sockets or `connect() / sendto() / recvfrom()` for UDP sockets.

My question is, when does kernal starts receiving and buffering packets to socket buffers? As soon as `bind()` has been called explicitely with non-ephemeral port? Or does it starts with first calls which deals with receiving like: `accept() / connect() / recvfrom()`?

For TCP sockets it doesn't matter, as sender will stop when socket receive buffer has been full. But for UDP socket, kernel will start discarding data if it starts buffering as soon as bound, and so I cannot have bound sockets staying around without starting `recvfrom()` sequences.

Comment: I don't think that this question is on-topic here. But in short: `recv` only reads from the buffer, so the filling of the buffer had to be started before, i.e. in UDP after `bind` is called.

Comment: may be I should move it to stackoverflow then? how do I do that?

Comment: You can delete the question here and create a new one there.

Comment: It depends on socket type. For SOCK_DGRAM, as soon as you bind, the stack will start buffering UDP packets. The default size is usually small, < 32k. For SOCK_STREAM, you need to listen or SYN will be dropped. You need to accept for SYN ACK, and then the other side can start sending data. Technically, the connecting side could send the SYN with data, but not many system do that, I don't think. Some do.